# Stop Xbox 360 controller from controlling Windows 10. Steam NOT installed

Tags: windows-10, game-controller

I like to control my mouse cursor with an Xbox 360 controller and joytokey. I've been doing it since Windows 7. However, ever since I have upgraded to Windows 10, the joysticks and buttons on the Xbox 360 controller now control the Win 10 UI without any 3rd part software whatsoever. For example, when I open the start menu I can navigate around with the left joystick and press A on the controller to open an app. The same sort of behavior occurs throughout the Windows UI.

I want to turn this off and use the controller exclusively through joytokey. Most people assume it is a setting in Steam. I don't have Steam installed on this PC and I have never had Steam installed on this PC. It seems to be a native Win 10 setting.

Can somebody help me figure out how to disable it? A setting or a registry value or anything.

I found a similar question on answers.microsoft.com (the most helpful site on the internet) which received no answer. There's also a question here on SU where the solutions are all Steam oriented and the controller is an Xbox One controller.

Edit: Corrected question that it is a Xbox 360 controller, not an Xbox One controller.

Answer (score 4):

I found myself a solution for this problem. Here are the steps:

1. Open "**Device Manager**".
2. Find "**Xbox 360 Peripherals**".
3. Select "**Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows**" and choose "**Update driver**".
4. Choose "**Browse my computer for driver software**" and choose "**Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer**".
5. Choose "**Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 2.1.0.1349 [13/08/2009]**" and then "**Next**".
6. Restart your Windows.

So I think the driver "**Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 10.0.18362.1 [18/03/2019]**" is the root problem.

Notes:
- There are only 2 drivers available locally in Windows 10 for "**Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows**" the first is "**2009 version**" and the other one is "**2019 version**".
- "**2019 version**" is capable to make your controller to "**act as a mouse natively**" on Windows 10.

I hope this solution will help you. Cheers!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you. I have searched far and wide, and this is the first answer that actually solves the issue. The answers at microsoft and other places are so frustrating. Just want to add, my Windows 10 didn't have 2.1.0... driver so I downloaded it here: https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-au/d/xbox-360-controller-for-windows

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now I have a problem that **Xbox 360 Wireless Receiver for Windows Version: 2.1.0.1349 [13/08/2009]** doesn't appear on the list .I tried installing the driver from Greth's comment, but it wouldn't install due to some installation files being missing... bad exe?

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to use a wired controller, do the following:**

1. Download the cab file "Microsoft - Game Devices, Other hardware - XBOX 360 Controller For Windows" from: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=%20Microsoft%20-%20Game%20Devices%2C%20Other%20hardware%20-%20XBOX%20360%20Controller%20For%20Windows%20

- Last Updated "8/12/2009"
- Size "2.5 MB"

2. Use 7-Zip to extract the cab file. This will result in a folder that contains:

- two folders "x64" & "x86"
- and three files: "INF Failures.txt", "xusb21.cat", & "xusb21.inf".

3. Open "control panel" and search for and navigate to "device manager".
4. Click on the "View" tab and select "Show hidden devices".
5. In "device manager" scroll down and you will eventually see "Xbox 360 Peripherals". Click it.
6. Right click on "Xbox 360 Controller for Windows" and select "Update Driver Software".
7. Click on "Browse my computer for driver software".
8. Click on "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
9. Click on "Have Disk..." in the lower right corner of the window.
10. Click on "Browse..." and navigate into the extracted folder from earlier that contains the driver.
11. Select the "xusb21.inf" file then click "Open".
12. Click "OK".
13. Click "Next" then the driver should install.
14. You will be asked to "restart your computer".  Do it when you are ready so that the changes will go into effect.
15. You should be all set. Hopefully this will work for you.

**If you want to Use a bluetooth controller, then do the following:**

1. Open "control panel" and search for and navigate to "device manager".
2. Click on the "View" tab and select "Show hidden devices".
3. In "device manager" scroll down and you will eventually see "Human Interface Devices". Click it.
4. Right click on "Bluetooth XINPUT compatible  device" and select "Update Driver Software".
5. Click on "Browse my computer for driver software".
6. Click on "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer".
7. Select "Bluetooth HID Device".
8. Click on "Next".
9. Restart your computer.
10. You should be all set. Hopefully this will work for you.