# Disable Xbox 360 controller in UWP apps like windows store and start menu

Tags: windows-10, xbox360

Windows has implemented tools for developers under the UWP (Universal Windows Platform) that steal button inputs from Xbox controllers (i.e. button inputs will be mapped to custom functions in specific apps) with no system-wide way to disable this. The implementation of UWP is half-baked and intermittent across the windows 10 operating system. This presents a problem of double input if one would like to use a third party software, such as Controller Companion, to map inputs on their gamepad to keystrokes and mouse movement. How can one disable the UWP controller input?

Comment: Here are clear instructions of a solution that worked for me:
https://superuser.com/a/1722822/1695467

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now disable Windows' inbuilt half-baked controller support with a registry edit ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1495#issuecomment-745586048)).

Create a new key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Input\Settings\ControllerProcessor\ControllerToVKMapping` and add a DWORD value named "Enabled" and set to 0.

No other solution I could find seemed to work in my case. Note that I have only tested on Windows 11 with the Controller Companion app, but I believe it should work for Windows 10. I use Xbox Series X controllers through a wireless adapter.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have found the following questions that are duplicates of this question. I did try and flag as such but they do not have accepted answers so it wouldn't let me.
Duplicates: https://superuser.com/questions/1508391/stop-xbox-360-controller-from-controlling-windows-10-steam-not-installed/1721432#1721432, https://superuser.com/questions/1173133/how-to-disable-xbox-one-controller-in-uwp-apps-like-windows-store-in-windows-10

Comment: I do believe my answer applies to all of them - trying to get the word out as this was an annoying issue for me and it was not easy to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.
Install an older version of the Xbox driver through device manager. This will disable the input to new windows apps built with UWP, but should still function with other, older software including games, etc. It specifically works with Controller Companion.

Here is the link: [Microsoft - Game Devices, Other hardware - XBOX 360 Controller For Windows](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=%20Microsoft%20-%20Game%20Devices%2C%20Other%20hardware%20-%20XBOX%20360%20Controller%20For%20Windows%20)

1. Download the "Microsoft - Game Devices, Other hardware - XBOX 360
               Controller For Windows" cabinet file with the 2009 drivers.
2. Extract the cabinet file to a folder (use 7zip or similar software).
3. Go to Device Manager and double-click the xbox 360 controller under
   xbox peripherals.
4. Go to Drivers tab, click Update drivers, click
       "Browse my Computer...", click "Let me pick from a list of
       drivers...", click "Have Disk...", navigate to the extracted cabinet
       folder that you created in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=xbox+controller

and click on the 6.3.9600.16384 version of the xbox 360 driver for win 8.1 or later.

http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2016/02/20844731_e19c69388a4a59f2e752f92ebaacbf3cddf3e4fd.cab

can confirm version of the driver works to disable this awful awful "feature" on windows 10.